# Javascript payments within php

Tags: php, javascript, payment

Basically what I was trying to do was to let users have the option of buying articles on my site. They would see a snippet of the article, pay with paypal, and without the page actually refreshing, the rest of the article is revealed

I don't want someone to build the whole thing (since that would take an internet eternity) I just want to get pointers on how I would go about doing so.

**EDIT:**
Not talking about the payment part (I have a paypal business account and have everything set up) But the actual javascript it would take to build it

I tried going to the xdevelopers site on paypal but all they had was a button that you put on the site -_- hardly what I was looking for

Much appreciated

Comment: @downvoter what did I say wrong? Ive done the research but can't seem to find what I was looking for. Im not asking anyone to build it, just advice

Comment: You should take a look into AJAX.

Comment: I didn't downvote but your question is overly broad. Look into AJAX, sessions, cookies, PayPal API.

Comment: Basically you should just take a look at the Paypal documentation. There is a complete description on how to implement it to let users buy articles. Really easy to set up and it provides you with a sandbox to test things in. After the user has completed the purchase, verify its unique "purchase" id that Paypal gives to you and if it's correct, display the entire article.

Comment: If the rest of the article reveals without refreshing, that implies you've sent the full article. What's to stop someone from just viewing the page source and reading all they want?

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to offer payment via paypal without a web page that goes to paypal.  It might be possible for you to open a new browser window and do the paypal payment stuff in that window and then when you determine that payment has been received, you can close that window and then show the extra content in the original window.

But, you won't be able to just run a paypal transaction in your own window on your own site.   Paypal customers are explicitly instructed to not enter paypal credentials into any non-paypal site because that's how scammers steal your paypal ID.

Comment: The transaction would be made in an iframe window

Comment: I would not put any paypal credentials into an iframe window because one cannot tell its secure origin.  It could easily be a scam to steal your paypal credentials.  I don't understand why they closed your question.  You could have phrased it better, but I understood what you were trying to do.